# How to unlock ActiveMQ Artemis broker

Tags: activemq-artemis

I did something to lock my ActiveMQ Artemis 2.8.1 broker. I needed to run `> ./artemis data exp` to get data on my queue setup. It failed to run, giving an error saying that the broker was locked: /var/lib/[broker]/lock

So I stopped the broker and ran the `data exp` successfully, but now when I try to start the broker I get the same error, and I don't know how to stop whatever was started by `data exp`.

```
Error: There is another process using the server at /var/lib/broker1/lock.  Cannot start the process!*
```

So how do I unlock the broker in this situation? I've tried using `systemctl` to restart Artemis all together, but that didn't do anything. And the Artemis tab is missing entirely from Console.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to simply remove the lock file at `/var/lib/broker1/lock` and then start the broker again.

Comment: I gave that a try. I can delete the file inside /var/lib/[broker]/lock, it's called cli.lock. I go back to /var/lib/[broker]/bin and run ./artemis run, but I get the same error (Error: There is another process using the server at /var/lib/broker1/lock. Cannot start the process!)  and the cli.lock file reappears.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: Artemis 2.8.1  I also have some errors in the output when starting the broker. https://pastebin.com/AGEDZuMx  And the Artemis tab is missing from Console.

Comment: I also tried rebooting. The service looks like it's running OK, but the broker is not accessible (stomp.py) and the Artemis tab is still missing from Console.

Comment: The error from the pastebin indicates the user who's running the broker doesn't have permission to access the journal files.

Comment: When you say "the service looks like it's running OK" what exactly do you mean? What does the broker's log file indicate?

Comment: When I start Artemis with systemctl, and then check the status, everything looks good: "artemis-service is now running ".  But if I try to do anything with the broker -- connect from a client, stop or run it, issues appear. 

Trying to run stop, I get an error starting with "Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1 (file:/opt/artemis/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar)" 

For run, I get the lock error.

Comment: What does the broker's log file indicate after you start it? Is it the same as the pastebin you provided earlier?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209473/discussion-between-horseatingweeds-and-justin-bertram).

Comment: Did you get this sorted?

Comment: Hi Justin. Yes. I have some log files set to root owner.